# Grouping photos in QListView PyQt5 by date

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to create a gallery view in PyQT5. I am currently trying to group the photos (grey boxes) in months as seen below. I am reading the file location and the date taken of the images through a SQL database.

[image]

So far I have managed to lazy load all of the images into the `QtWidgets.QListView` using a basic model, seen below. I have never worked with PyQt before and I am getting a little lost. Can anyone help me?

```
import sys
import CustomWidgets as cw
import platform
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import os
import threading
import math
import pyodbc

# GUI FILE
from PhotosPage import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # connect tab Pages
        self.ui.PageButton_Photos.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.PhotosPage))
        self.ui.PageButton_Albums.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.AlbumsPage))
        self.ui.PageButton_People.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.PeoplePage))
        self.ui.PageButton_Groups.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.GroupsPage))
        
        # hide Album info 
        self.ui.AlbumInfoFrame.hide()
        
        # set model for photos
        model = TestListModel(self.ui.PhotosFrame)
        self.ui.PhotosFrame.setModel(model)
        self.ui.PhotosFrame.setSpacing(5)
        
        self.show()
        
      
class TestListModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.list = parent
        self.fileList = os.listdir('P:/PhotoSorterInfo/MiniPhotos')
        # self.setFileList() 
        
    def setFileList(self):
        print(self.readDataBase()[0])
    
    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self.fileList)

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if not self.list.indexWidget(index):
                button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
                button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("P:/PhotoSorterInfo/MiniPhotos/" + self.fileList[index.row()]))
                button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 175))
                button.setFlat(True)
                self.list.setIndexWidget(index, button)
            return QtCore.QVariant()
        
        if role == QtCore.Qt.SizeHintRole:
            return QtCore.QSize(300, 175)

    def columnCount(self, index):
        pass
    
    def readDataBase(self, id=10):
        returnInfo = DataBase.execute(
                        """SELECT Files_tbl.ID, Files_tbl.Name, Files_tbl.FileType, Files_tbl.Width, Files_tbl.Height, Files_tbl.Size, Files_tbl.DateTaken, FileDirectories_tbl.FileLocation
                        FROM Files_tbl, FileDirectories_tbl
                        WHERE FileDirectories_tbl.ID = Files_tbl.FileLocation
                        ORDER BY DateTaken DESC;""")

        # place info into dictionary 
        Photos = []
        results = []
        columns = [column[0] for column in DataBase.description]

        for row in returnInfo.fetchall():
            Photos.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))
            
        return Photos
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    filePath = os.getcwd()

    DataBase = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=' + filePath + r'\Database\PhotosDatabase.accdb;')
    DataBase = DataBase.cursor()

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Sorry, help you with *what*?

Comment: grouping images by date, as seen in the picture above. Right now my code just loads all of the images in one big group

Comment: Item geometry in a QListView is done internally, through a complex system that deals with item size hints and actually "loaded" items. I'm sorry but your question is really too broad: while what you're asking *is* doable, it's also very difficult: for instance, one of the main problems is that batch-layouting (which is done for performance reasons) is based on the assumption that items have a common size, but if you need "grouping", that requires knowing the whole model before that. Answering your question means developing all that from scratch, and that's not the purpose of StackOverflow.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, your question is, somehow, interesting. But, due to the complexity of the base concept, you're practically asking us to code it for you. As stated in the comments of your previous questions, creating an image gallery is not an easy task, and everybody that faced that problem had to compromise between usability and performance (including memory usage and disk caching); a directory could have thousands of small images, or even few rather big ones: the implementation has to consider *all* cases, and such an implementation requires deep knowledge and thinking.

Comment: If I was to start building a version of QListView from scratch would you have any clue what I could look at to get started?

Comment: The best way is *always* to carefully, patiently study the source. [This](//code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qlistview.cpp.html) is a very good place to start with, as it will show the source with a very good interface that dramatically helps understanding and code browsing. Please note that you should also consider the [graphics view framework](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html): it's much more complex, but also more flexible, and could be useful for such an application. Take your time, and be aware: its learning curve is quite steep, but it's also *really* powerful.

Comment: This does not seem to be a sutable task for a beginner. You should start with something much simpler. I do not think that `QListView` provides API for any grouping as you need. If I were you, I would write a custom widget for this. It seems to me much easier than hacking `QListView`. But as I say, this is hardly achievable for a beginner. And nobody is going to write code for you here on SO. Sorry.